# How to Prove: Any error in a sequence of digits including its check digit will no longer be congruent to 0 mod 10

Tags: elementary-number-theory

***The Problem:*** Consider choosing the check digit such that the digits of the number (including the check digit) sum to $0 \pmod{10}$. For instance, the check digit $x$ for $13863$ is $1+3+8+6+3+x \equiv 0 \pmod{10} $, so $x=9$. The full number sent is $138639$. Prove that an error in any one digit (including the check digit) is detected by this scheme.

Where I am currently stuck with my proof at this point I have been stuck for awhile so if anybody could shed some light on how to proceed that would be much appreciated,

Proof. Consider the following sequence of digits in which each digit ranges from $(0-9)$ and the following sum of digits is congruent to $0 \pmod{10}$,

$$a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n+x \equiv 0 \pmod{10}$$

If there exists an error in any single digit say, $a_i'$ then we know that $|a_i - a_i'|\leq 9$ where $|a_i - a_i'| \neq 0$ since this would imply they are the same digit.

This was my original approach which was to show that the error can add at most $9$ to the sum I am struggling to show how this would result in a sum that is not congruent to $0 \pmod{10}$.

Also, let me know if I posted this to the wrong place and/or formatting is a problem. Thanks.

Comment: If I understood correctly, since a error would mean at most $9$ and the original number is $0$ mod $10$ then by noticing $\pm 1, \pm 2, \cdots, \pm 9$ mod 10 can never be $0$ mod $10$ thus the scheme works?

Comment: Start with a special case by assuming $a'_i = a_i+e$ with $e$ being an error value. Then calculate $(a_1+...+a_n+x+e)\mod 10$ by applying the distributive formula $(a + b) \mod n = [(a \mod n) + (b \mod n)] \mod n $ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo )

Comment: @Maksim Ah okay this makes a lot of sense and helped me proceed further with my proof, thanks!